# Need help inserting useEffect state on nextjs page for document.queryselector

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I need help inputting useEffect hook in order to make the document.queryselector work at the bottom of the code. What the javascript basically does is it take the number and a circle progress bar and align the number and the bar to move simultaneously every digit that it is incremented. I just need help adding the useEffect hook and making it work when the page refreshes. :

```
import { SearchIcon } from "@heroicons/react/outline";
import { useState } from "react";
import News from "./News";
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion"; 
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import {useEffect} from "react";


export default function Widgets({newsResults}) {
  const[articleNum, setArticleNum] = useState(3);
  return (
    <div className="xl:w-[600px] lg:inline ml-8 space-y-5">
        <div className="w-[90%] xl:w-[75%] sticky top-0 bg-white py-1.5 z-50">
            <div className="flex items-center p-3 rounded-full bg-red-300 relative">
                <SearchIcon className="h-5 z-50 text-gray-500 "/>
                <input className="absolute inset-0 rounded-full pl-11 border-gray-500 text-gray-700 focus:shadow-lg focus:bg-white bg-gray-100" type="text" placeholder="Search RUbars" />
            </div>
        </div>

        {/* <div className="text-gray-700 space-y-3 bg-gray-100 rounded-xl pt-2 w-[90%] xl:w-[75%]">
            <h4 className="font-bold text-xl px-4">Whats happening</h4>
        <AnimatePresence>
        {newsResults.slice(0,articleNum).map((article)=>(
          <motion.div key={article.title} initial={{opacity: 0 }} animate={{opacity: 1}} exit={{opacity: 0}} transition={{duration: 1}}>
           <News key={article.title} article={article}/>
           </motion.div>
        ))}
        </AnimatePresence>
        <button onClick={()=>setArticleNum(articleNum + 3)} className="text-rose-300 pl-4 pb-3 hover:text-rose-400">Show more</button>
        </div> */}
        <div className="text-gray-700 space-y-3 bg-gray-100 pt-2 rounded-xl w-[90%] xl:w-[75%]">
          <h4 className="font-bold text-xl px-4">Capacity</h4>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="circular-progress">
            <span class="progress-value">0%</span>
            </div>
            <span className="text">Olde Queens</span>
              <div class="circular-progress">
              <span className="progress-value">0%</span>
            </div>
            <span className="text1">Golden Rail</span>
            <div class="circular-progress1">
              <span className="progress-value1">0%</span>
            </div>
            <span className="text">Huey&apos;s Knight Club</span>
            <button className="text-rose-300 pl-4 pb-3 hover:text-rose-400">Show more</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

let circularProgress = document.querySelector(".circular-progress"),
    progressValue = document.querySelector(".progress-value");

let progressStartValue = 0,
    progressEndValue = 24,
    speed = 40;

let progress = setInterval(() =>{
    progressStartValue++;

    progressValue.textContent = `${progressStartValue}%`
    circularProgress.style.background = `conic-gradient(#E0115F ${progressStartValue * 3.6}deg, #ededed 0deg)`

    if(progressStartValue == progressEndValue){
        clearInterval(progress);
    }
    console.log(progressStartValue);

}, speed);
```

I know it has to look something like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let circularProgress = document.querySelector(".circular-progress");
    console.log(circularProgress)
  }, []);
```

But I am not really sure how to insert it at the bottom.

Comment: use ref to get the reference of the circular-progress div

Comment: could you modify the code for me and insert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the state for progress and put your useEffect function inside the Widgets component and when your state changed your component retendered to update the view template.

**Code Edit For Multiple Progress with different end value and speed**

```html
export default function Widgets({newsResults}) {
  const[articleNum, setArticleNum] = useState(3);
  const[progressValue1, setProgressValue1] = useState(0);
  const[progressValue2, setProgressValue2] = useState(0);
  const[progressValue3, setProgressValue3] = useState(0);

  let progressEndValue1 = 24, progressEndValue2 = 34, progressEndValue3 = 44,
  progressStartValue1 = 0, progressStartValue2 = 0, progressStartValue3 = 0;

useEffect(() => {
  const progress1 = setInterval(() =>{
    if(progressEndValue1 > progressStartValue1){
      progressStartValue1++;
      setProgressValue1(progressStartValue1);
      console.log(progressValue1)
    }
    else{
      clearInterval(progress1);
    }
  }, 200);
  const progress2 = setInterval(() =>{
    if(progressEndValue2 > progressStartValue2){
      progressStartValue2++
      setProgressValue2(progressStartValue2);
    }
    else{
      clearInterval(progress2);
    }
  }, 300);
  const progress3 = setInterval(() =>{
    if(progressEndValue3 > progressStartValue3){
      progressStartValue3++;
      setProgressValue3(progressStartValue3);
    }
    else{
      clearInterval(progress3);
    }
  }, 400);
}, []);
  return (
    <div className="xl:w-[600px] lg:inline ml-8 space-y-5">
        <div className="w-[90%] xl:w-[75%] sticky top-0 bg-white py-1.5 z-50">
            <div className="flex items-center p-3 rounded-full bg-red-300 relative">
              <SearchIcon className="h-5 z-50 text-gray-500 "/>
                <input className="absolute inset-0 rounded-full pl-11 border-gray-500 text-gray-700 focus:shadow-lg focus:bg-white bg-gray-100" type="text" placeholder="Search RUbars" />
            </div>
        </div>

        {/* <div className="text-gray-700 space-y-3 bg-gray-100 rounded-xl pt-2 w-[90%] xl:w-[75%]">
            <h4 className="font-bold text-xl px-4">Whats happening</h4>
        <AnimatePresence>
        {newsResults.slice(0,articleNum).map((article)=>(
          <motion.div key={article.title} initial={{opacity: 0 }} animate={{opacity: 1}} exit={{opacity: 0}} transition={{duration: 1}}>
           <News key={article.title} article={article}/>
           </motion.div>
        ))}
        </AnimatePresence>
        <button onClick={()=>setArticleNum(articleNum + 3)} className="text-rose-300 pl-4 pb-3 hover:text-rose-400">Show more</button>
        </div> */}
        <div className="text-gray-700 space-y-3 bg-gray-100 pt-2 rounded-xl w-[90%] xl:w-[75%]">
          <h4 className="font-bold text-xl px-4">Capacity</h4>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="circular-progress" style={{background: `conic-gradient(#E0115F ${progressValue1 * 3.6}deg, #ededed 0deg)`}}>
            <span className="progress-value">{progressValue1}%</span>
            </div>
            <span className="text">Olde Queens</span>
              <div className="circular-progress" style={{background: `conic-gradient(#E0115F ${progressValue2 * 3.6}deg, #ededed 0deg)`}}>
              <span className="progress-value">{progressValue2}%</span>
            </div>
            <span className="text1">Golden Rail</span>
            <div className="circular-progress1" style={{background: `conic-gradient(#E0115F ${progressValue3 * 3.6}deg, #ededed 0deg)`}}>
              <span className="progress-value1">{progressValue3}%</span>
            </div>
            <span className="text">Huey&apos;s Knight Club</span>
            <button className="text-rose-300 pl-4 pb-3 hover:text-rose-400">Show more</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: how do I target the .circular-progress and the .progress-value? Because these are the values that are in my css file as well. Also, when I input that code, it doesn't move the circle progress bar

Comment: Oh nvm it works! Thank you!  Is there a way where I can change the circular-progress and progress-value for each seperate one? Instead of changing them all?

Comment: @iamundertaker Salam, you can use for every one state. const[progressValue1, setProgressValue1] = useState(0);
const[progressValue2, setProgressValue2] = useState(0);

Comment: yea but then do I have to add progressStartvalue1 & 2? Do you think you can write that code too? Ill upvote your answer and mark it right

Comment: @iamundertaker Check it now I added multi state for your progress bar.
it will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you it works! how much experience do you have with this? And how did you get better to improve your skills?